# Maven-javadoc-plugin ClassNotFound while trying to register Taglet

Tags: java, maven, configuration, javadoc

In a multi-module maven project, I have the javadoc configuration set up in the parent pom.xml, including pointing to the jarfile for my taglet.

This is working fine in one of the sub-modules, but not in the other.

The best guess I have is that the taglet code has a dependency which is met in the first but not the second. Unfortunately, Maven doesn't explicitly tell me which class it couldn't resolve. And I don't want the second to depend upon the first; architecturally it's the other way around.

Any suggestions on how to get more debugging information rather than the bare error line would be welcome.

Error messages I want to get more detail from:

```
[ERROR] javadoc: error - Error - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException thrown while trying to register Taglet xalan2jtaglet.XSLUsageTag...
[ERROR] /home/keshlam/git/xalan-java-mvn/serializer/src/main/java/org/apache/xml/serializer/AttributesImplSerializer.java:37: error: unknown tag: xsl.usage
[ERROR]  * @xsl.usage internal
[ERROR]    ^
```

Plugin configuration:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <groups>
        <group>
          <title>XPath</title>
          <packages>org.apache.xpath*</packages>
        </group>
        <group>
          <title>Document Table Model (DTM)</title>
          <packages>org.apache.xml.dtm*</packages>
        </group>          
        <group>
          <title>Utilities</title>
          <packages>org.apache.xml.utils*</packages>
        </group>
        <group>
          <title>Xalan Other</title>
          <packages>org.apache.xalan.client:org:org.apache.xalan.extensions:org.apache.xalan.res:org.apache.xalan.stree:org.apache.xalan.trace:org.apache.xalan.xslt</packages>
        </group>
        <group>
          <title>Xalan Extensions</title>
          <packages>org.apache.xalan.lib*</packages>
        </group>
        <group>
          <title>Serializers</title>
          <packages>org.apache.xml.serialize*:org.apache.xalan.serialize</packages>
        </group>
        <group>
          <title>SAX 2</title>
          <packages>org.xml.sax*</packages>
        </group>
        <group>
          <title>DOM 2</title>
          <packages>org.w3c.dom*</packages>
        </group>
        <group>
          <title>XSLTC Core</title>
          <packages>org.apache.xalan.xsltc*</packages>
        </group>
      </groups>

      <!-- GONK: classloader problem for @xsl.usage, only in serializer module.
           Unclear if it's disliking the jar, or if there's a dependency
           present in the xalan module but not here.
      -->
      <taglets>
            <taglet>
              <tagletClass>xalan2jtaglet.XSLUsageTag</tagletClass>
              <tagletpath>${basedir}/tools/xalan2jtaglet.jar</tagletpath>
            </taglet>       
      </taglets>

    </configuration>

        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <id>aggregate</id>
            <inherited>false</inherited>        
            <reports>
              <report>aggregate</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
          <reportSet>
            <id>default</id>
            <reports>
              <report>javadoc</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Yes, I tried the black-magic solution of deleting/refreshing the Maven repository. No help, alas.

Trying to run javadoc directly, I *think* the problem is that the plugin relies on tools.jar or equivalent. I've been playing with the various solutions in other questions more specifically about tools.jar in Maven, but they haven't been resolving the problem. However, this *might* explain why one module is OK and the other isn't -- they have different dependencies, and one of the dependencies in the xalan module that serializer doesn't have is probably carrying an appropriate reference to tools.jar.

As an ugly kluge-around I could try adding dependencies until I figure out which one is making the difference....